# Сохранение через FileChooser

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем добрый день, я хочу чтобы пользователь выбирал где сохранять файл сам через FileChooser в JavaFX, но когда он выбирает директорию например D:\File\ а тут мне выдают сообщение что я не могу сохранять файлы в данной директории!!! Я администратор и я не могу сохранять, печально... Как сделать так, чтобы я мог сохранять там, где захочу?

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Select directory for save");
    fileChooser.setInitialFileName("decryptImage");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image", "*.png"));
    File newImageFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(expandOverlapButton.getScene().getWindow());
```

А далее я использую объект newImageFile в методе ImageIO.write(...);

Comment: Наверное имеет смысл выложить код + добавить stacktrace. По-хорошему такого быть не должно. Если выложите можно будет детально посмотреть.

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski вот отрывок кода, stacktrace добавить не могу, т.к. исключительной ситуации не возникает

Comment: Что выдаёт сообщение? Куда выдаёт? Как дословно это сообщение звучит?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev D:\decryotImage.png У вас нет разрешения на сохранение файла в этом месте. Обратитесь к администратору сети для получения разрешения. Хотите выполнить сохранение в папке "Изображения" вместо этого? А само сообщение в окошке обычном виндовском, с час мб скрин запилю

Comment: Скажите а запускаете вы из командной строки или IDE?

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski я запускаю из IDE, теперь вот собрал проект уже в jar файл, но тут та же самая фигня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы исключить недоразумений можете попробовать запустить вот этот код и проверить будет ли происходить сохранение?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Select directory for save");
        fileChooser.setInitialFileName("decryptImage");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image", "*.jpg"));
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);

        if (file != null) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            URL url = new URL("https://www.google.by/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png");

            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            imageView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null));
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageView.getImage(),
                    null), "png", file);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Если результат будет тот же, то хотя бы будет понятно, что ошибка где-то в локальном энвароменте поскольку данный код работает на моем локальном компьютере. И если это все-таки будет так, то будем думать дальше.

Comment: Результат вашего кода такой же, как и результат моего, выскакивает то же сообщение

Comment: @ProstoCoder по все видимости и `Files.isWritable(file.toPath().getRoot())` будет выдавать `false` в Вашем случае. Осталось удостовериться, что Ваш пользователь действительно администратор. То есть узнав своего пользователя через команду `echo %UserName%` и зайдя в `Advanced user management` в `Groups` `Администраторы` Вы видите того самого пользователя?

Comment: да, я администратор

Comment: Вот еще предположение - командную строку запускает "Run as administrator"? Даже если вы и являетесь администратором, попробуйте командную строку, как администратор запустить.

Comment: Да, командную строку я могу запустить от имени администратора

Comment: @ProstoCoder имеется в виду запустить командную строку из-под администратора, а в ней сделать вызов приложения. В данном случае вся java утилита должна будет крутиться в space администратора и подобная ошибка не должна воспроизвестись. Вы вроде бы говорили, что вы сделали executable jar. Так вот идея его запустить из этой командной строки.

Comment: ага, с запуском из командной от админа всё получилось, но вот только это совсем неудобно, а батник я чёт не совсем догнал как создавать, чтобы запускать от админа программу по пути. ЕЩЁ ВАЖНО: тут я так понимаю java потеряет смысл, ну как бы на mac os оно не потянет, только на винде, а мне важно сохранить кроссплатформенность, есть идеи?

Comment: Нет, не совсем так. Проблема в Ваших личных настройках. То, что все заработало из-под администратора говорит о том, что все же Ваши права сконфигурированы не совсем корректно. Уверен, что Ваше запакованное в jar архив приложение заработает на любом другом компьютере. А ошибка подобного рода возникнет в любом другом приложении. Иными словами это совсем не связано с java.

Comment: это да, спасибо вам